# Exit animations in react framer-motion not appearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I am creating a space viewer app and using Framer motion for the animations. What I am aiming for is the starting component that is called `loading` will have an exit animation upon being clicked. However at the moment all of my components are failing to have exit animations. They simply lead to other components as if I was only using react-router.

My app.js looks like this

```
<AnimatePresence  /* I have tried to put exitBeforeEnter here, it does nothing*/ >
<Route exact path="/" key="loading"  component={Loading} />
            <Route  path="/sol" key="menu"  component={Menu} />
```

And my `loading` component looks like this

```
 const loading = {
        start: {
         scale: 2,
       
        },
        out: {
          scale: .1,
        
        },
      };
      const pagetransition = {
        duration: 2,
      };
    return(
    <motion.div initial="start"
    animate="in"
   exit="out"
    variants={loading}
    transition={pagetransition}    className="loadingScreen"
    >
<NavLink to="/sol"><button ><p >Enter System</p></button></NavLink>
    </motion.div>
```

At the moment, none of my pages have exit animations, but they do have entrance animations, so I know that I am not doing things totally wrong. I have [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-goldstine-2x5s8?file=/src/components/loading.js) where all of my code is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in the code sandbox. Using Framer-Motion to do route transitions is quite easy but a little involved. First you have to use `AnimatePresence` outside the `<Switch> ... </Switch>`. Then you need to have some key in `Switch` for Framer-motion to keep track of the routes.

We use `location` for the key and inorder to use the `useLocation()` hook in App.js, we'll need to surround `<App />` in `index.js` with `Router`. So that's what I've done.

Here are the changes that I've explained until now.

In index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In App.js

```
import { Switch, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        // all the routes here
      </Switch>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```

Then in loading.js, surround the entire thing with a `motion.div`. This `motion.div` is what will animate. I've done a simple left to right for entering, and right to left for exit.

Changes made in loading.js

```
  const routeTransition = {
    hide: {
      x: "100vw"
    },

    animate: {
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        delay: 0.75,
        duration: 0.75,
        when: "beforeChildren",
        staggerChildren: 0.5
      }
    },

    exit: {
      x: "-100vw",
      transition: {
        duration: 0.75
      }
    }
  };

return (

    <motion.div // this is the div that will animate the entire route
      variants={routeTransition}
      initial="hide"
      animate="animate"
      exit="exit"
    > 
      <motion.div // this div will only animate the button
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        transition={pagetransition}
        className="loadingScreen"
      >
        <NavLink to="/sol">
          <button>
            <p>Enter System</p>
          </button>
        </NavLink>
      </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
  );
```